# Selenium webdriver find_element_by_xpath takes time

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

If element does not exist on the page `find_element_by_xpath()` takes too much time hanging the test execution. Is there any way to set timeout to `find_element_by_xpath()` function in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an [implicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits) using this code -

```
ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

This makes the WebDriver wait for 10 secs before raising an error when you try to find an element on the webpage.